# Indexing tons of documents to elasticsearch index with php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm new for elasticsearch. So far I've managed to create index, mapping and indexing documents.

With PHP I can add documents from mysql. By looping through all the mysql rows I add the documents one by one.

```
foreach($items as $item){
$ch = curl_init();
$json_request = '{
  "title": "'.$item['title'].'",
  "description":  "'.$item['description'].'",
  "price":  "'.$item['price'].'"
}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_request);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

It works for small amount of data. But when I use it for 500 000 items, it took days indexing.

Could some please tell me how I can do better?
Thanks.

Comment: You could look at curl_multi_exec [Manual](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

Two things I'd do:

1. First, if you want to keep Elasticsearch continually updated with
   the data from mysql I'd take a look at the Elasticsearch MySQL
   River: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc
2. Second, I'd look at the Elasticsearch Bulk API:
   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html
   This will let you make a single call to insert large numbers of
   documents with a single API call and is far more efficient when
   loading large numbers of documents.

Comment: What did you try? And what do you mean crash your browser? This is back end code running on the server - personally I would be testing it from the command line. I don't see how it can crash a browser as it does not send anything to the browser.